# Which is positive work and which is negative work when an object is lifted upwards by force A when already the gravity is acting on it from below?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, work, conventions, displacement

If I lift a book upwards,then by which force is the negative work done; is it done by the force effected by me or by the force of gravity which is pulling the book from the ground below??

Comment: Do you know the equation for work?  Think about the dot product and how that would tie into this.

Answer (score -1):

Use the dot product. The angle in your case is 180 degrees.